# MAC os x 10.8+ code signing certificate details

Tags: java, macos, code-signing-certificate

I want details of all code signing certificates installed on any macosx 10.8+ machines as well as details of the certificate like to see it's properties like certificateID, certificateDevID etc using java code. 
Currently i am using ProcessBuilder in java to get the output of the command "security find-identity -p codesigning -v" & parsing it output. It is listing all installed code signing certificates but not much details about the certificate. 
Any other approach or hack ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after some research & help
Parse the output of the command below
"**security find-identity -p code signing -v**"
it gives the names of all the certificated imported/installed